# How to open CFMEDIAPLAYER by clicking on a hyperlink

Tags: coldfusion, media-player

I have some video files available on my server. So i need to fetch all the videos. First i am getting all the posters from server and showing it in a  tag  in a loop. Now i want to open the mediaplayer if any of the images are clicked. The mediaplayer should open at the same place where the image is showing. Please let me know how to open the mediaplayer dynamically by clicking on the images.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Are you familiar with the cfcontent tag?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code. As written, this question will get closed. We need specific issues with which you are having issues.